# Задача на потоки

Tags: java, многопоточность

В самом условии: есть гостиница с номерами; клиент приходит, заселяется в номер или ждет пока освободится, если все занято. Какое-то время живет в номере, а потом его освобождает. 
Каждый клиент - это отдельный поток. 
Написал программу, но не пойму как описать main. Помогите пожалуйста сделать правильно.

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Hotel
{
    private boolean taken = false;
    public synchronized 
        void take() throws InterruptedException 
    {
        while(taken)
            wait();
        taken = true;
    }
    public synchronized void free()
    {
        taken = false;
        notifyAll();
    }
}
class Client implements Runnable
{
    private Hotel room;
    private final int id;
    private final int live;
    private Random rand = new Random(50);
    private void pause() throws InterruptedException
    {
        if(live==0) return;
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(rand.nextInt(live*250));
    }
    public Client(Hotel room, int ident, int l)
    {
        this.room = room;
        id = ident;
        live = l;
    }
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            while(!Thread.interrupted())
            {
                System.out.println(this+" "+"freed");
                pause();
                System.out.println(this+" "+"settled");
                room.take();
                System.out.println(this+" "+"live");
                pause();
                room.free();
            }
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e)
        {
            System.out.println(this+" "+"exiting via interrupt");
        }
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Client"+id;
    }
}
class Test
{
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Hotel h = new Hotel();
        for(int i=0; i<=50; i++)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(new Client(h, i, 10));
            t.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: У вас всё итак правильно. Что вас не устраивает? То, что люди продолжают заселяться? Или то, что живут в номере 1 тик?

Comment: У Java много высокоуровневых классов работы с многопоточностью и они проще, используйте лучше их.

Comment: @Dmig, консоль пустая получается

Comment: @oyashi, У меня консоль всё выводит, как надо

Comment: @Dmig, с этим кодом появляется ошибка <Static Error: This class does not have a static void main method accepting String[]>.

Comment: Проблема в том, что у вас три класса в одном, и компилятор ищет метод main(...) лишь в первом

Comment: @Dmig, все работает, разобрался, спасибо